# Disable white line in return

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to disable it?

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What editor is this?

Comment: I see that you haven't responded to my answer. Is there something I can add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(note: I think this feature only exists in Android Studio, not sure about
other editors).*

Go to: *Settings (<kbd>Crl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>) => "Languages & Frameworks" => "Flutter" => Disable "Show UI Guides for build methods"*

[image]

And the lines are removed:
[image]